# ruby require relative quesiton

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I am trying to learn how to make a ruby on rails app. I am stuck on the require_relative syntax. Currently I have a game_runner.rb file, that is not in the app directory, that is supposed to get a method (who_is_hider) from role.rb that is in models. Am I typing it correctly? When I run the current code I get an "uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord" error. This makes no sense since I have a application_record.rb file that has (self.abstract_class = true) inside. Thank you for your time.

[image]

game_runner.rb

```
require_relative './app/models/Role'
who_is_hider
```

role.rb

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :round
  belongs_to :player
  enum label: {seeker: 1, hider: 2, decoy: 3}

  validates :player_id, uniqueness: {scope: :round_id}

  def who_is_hider    
    p "made it here"   
  end
end
```

application_record.rb

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

Comment: Please, post the code and the error message as code and as text in your question. This is a programming site, not a photography site. Don't post photographs of your code and errors, we want to read, copy&paste, run, and analyze them, not critique your use of color and perspective. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I am stuck on the require_relative syntax. […] Am I typing it correctly? When I run the current code I get an "uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord" error.

Yes, your syntax is correct. If your syntax were incorrect, your code wouldn't even run in the first place, and you would get a `SyntaxError`. The fact that your code *does* run and produce a `NameError` exception shows without a doubt that your syntax is correct.

As an easy way to check whether your syntax is correct, you can

- visually inspect the syntax coloring in your editor,
- visually inspect the syntax coloring in the Stack Overflow question, if you post one,
- run `ruby -c` to check the syntax

The last one is the preferred option if you have it available, of course. But sometimes, you are writing code in an environment where you don't have a Ruby execution engine available, and in that case, you can at least use your editor or even the (admittedly not very good and easily confused) highlighting that Stack Overflow uses. While especially the latter one is not very good, it still *does* tend to highlight easy mistakes caused by typos, e.g. unterminated string literals.

Comment: Note: the code is so tiny that I cannot actually read it on my screen, and since it is a photograph, I am also unable to test it out for myself, but fortunately, since your question focuses on the syntax, it is possible to tell from the fact that your code does run and produce an error that is unrelated to syntax, that your syntax must be correct.

Comment: I added the code from game_runner.rb and role.rb. Sorry about the picture, it was meant to show that both files are in completely different folders. With game_runner in "its_not_me" and role in "/app/models". I want to be able to run the game_runner in terminal and call methods from models like role

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, you are using a single ruby file and expecting to load all rails environment? your Role model knows about ApplicationRecord because Rails loads a LOT of things on the background. If Rails is not in the middle then you have to explicitlly tell what thinks to load. You can require ApplicationRecord on the game_runner file or inside role.rb, but then you'll have to require ActiveRecord too.

I don't think it's a good idea to do what you are trying to do. If you wan't to run some script that depends on your environment, I'd recommend you to use a rake task, it will handle the loading of the environment. If you still want to make your game_runner.rb run as is, then you'll have to import everything the interpreter complains about until it works.